# Google Map Custom Marker not draggable

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have created a Google Map custom marker in a Vue component. I have set draggable = "true" but the marker is not draggable. How can I make the marker draggable and get the coordinates once it has been dragged?

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// basemap
<template>
  <div>
    <GmapMap :style="'height:500px'" :center="center" :zoom="zoom">
      <Location :location="location1"/>
    </GmapMap>
  </div>
</template>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Location
<template>
  <div>
      <GmapCustomMarker
        ref="editMarker"
        :marker="location.pos"
        :draggable="true"
        class="g_marker"
        alignment="center"
        :z-index="999"
      >
        <div style="background-color: red; width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 2px solid black;"></div>
      </GmapCustomMarker>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import GmapCustomMarker from "vue2-gmap-custom-marker";
```

Comment: You should wrap it in a map first. How do you want to drag it if it's just a single marker and there is no map around it?

Comment: @Andor Németh sorry it is wrapped around the map. This is the Location component that is housed inside another BaseMap component. I'll edit the question to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are utilizing [`vue2-gmap-custom-marker` package](https://github.com/eregnier/vue2-gmap-custom-marker), right? If so, it does not seem to support *dragging* option. But the following example demonstrates how to implement a *draggable marker* as a Vue component (which is based on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/QRuW8/)):

```
<template>
  <div :draggable="true" :style="{'position': 'absolute'}">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps";
/* global google */
export default {
  mixins: [VueGoogleMaps.MapElementMixin],
  props: {
    position: {
      type: Object,
      default: undefined
    }
  },
  methods: {},
  data() {
    return {
      current: null,
      origin: null
    };
  },
  provide() {
    const self = this;

    return this.$mapPromise.then(map => {
      class Overlay extends google.maps.OverlayView {
        constructor(map) {
          super();
          this.setMap(map);
          self.current = new google.maps.LatLng(
            self.position.lat,
            self.position.lng
          );
        }
        draw() {
          const container = self.$el;
          let pos = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(self.current);
          container.style.left = pos.x + "px";
          container.style.top = pos.y + "px";
        }
        onAdd() {
          const container = self.$el;
          const panes = this.getPanes();
          panes.floatPane.appendChild(container);

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(
            self.$map.getDiv(),
            "mouseleave",
            () => {
              google.maps.event.trigger(container, "mouseup");
            }
          );

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(container, "mousedown", e => {
            container.style.cursor = "move";
            self.$map.set("draggable", false);
            self.origin = e;

            const mouseMoveHandler = google.maps.event.addDomListener(
              self.$map.getDiv(),
              "mousemove",
              e => {
                let left = self.origin.clientX - e.clientX;
                let top = self.origin.clientY - e.clientY;
                let pos = self.$overlay
                  .getProjection()
                  .fromLatLngToDivPixel(self.current);
                let latLng = self.$overlay
                  .getProjection()
                  .fromDivPixelToLatLng(
                    new google.maps.Point(pos.x - left, pos.y - top)
                  );
                self.origin = e;
                self.current = latLng;
                this.draw();
              }
            );

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(container, "mouseup", () => {
              self.$map.set("draggable", true);
              container.style.cursor = "default";
              google.maps.event.removeListener(mouseMoveHandler);
            });
          });
        }
        onRemove() {
          self.$el.remove();
        }
      }
      this.$overlay = new Overlay(map);
    });
  },
  destroyed() {
    this.$overlay.setMap(null);
    this.$overlay = undefined;
  }
};
</script>
```

[Here is a **demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-pz51g)